# Create tags reputation

Tags: support

When I was browsing the list of [privileges](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), I noticed that you need 150 reputation to be able to create new tags, while you need 300 in other SE sites. Is this because parenting.SE is still in beta? If not, what is the reason for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Beta sites have lower requirements for privileges, in order to let the site self manage effectively.